# How to observe LiveData inside Custom View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

How should I observe a LiveData in a Custom View. I tried to cast it's context as lifecycleOwner but it makes some problems and doesn't work in all cases.
I tried to put a setter but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Views do not have lifecycle on their own. There are 3 approaches that I personally use, they are actually the same thing but one of them is adding a lifecycle while the others are without a lifecycle.

```
class MyCustomView  @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr){
    
    
    val myObserver = Observer<Long>{
        //whatever
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        liveData.observeForever(myObserver)
    }

    override fun onDetachFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachFromWindow()
        liveData.removeObserver(myObserver)
    }
}
```

This method manually observe/remove on attach/detach to window. I prefer it when I'm observing few livedata and it's simple/limited

---

Another option is to turn our custom view into a LifecycleOwner. I recommend this method for BaseCustomViews and some extremely huge and complicated views (like a Map navigation view). Also, remember that you need to manually notify the view about its parent getting destroyed (you can call the method directly or use a view tree navigation to call this function for all view which are the child of BaseCustomView).

```
abstract class BaseCustomView  @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), LifecycleOwner {
    protected val lifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this);

    override fun getLifecycle() = lifecycleRegistry
    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.RESUMED
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State. CREATED
    }

    @CallSuper
    open fun destroyLifecycle(){
        lifecycleRegistry.currentState = Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED
    }

    
    val myObserver = Observer<Long>{
        //whatever
    }

    init{
        liveData.observe(this, myObserver}
    }
}
```

---

If you prefer the first method, another option can be combining this 2 ideas, having a `BaseCustomView` which enables its children to observe LiveData easily.

```
abstract class BaseCustomView  @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
): RelativeLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    //a list to hold the list of observers and their LiveData
    private val autoObservers = ArrayList<Pair<LiveData<*>, Observer<*>>>()

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        for((liveData, observer) in autoObservers){
            liveData.observeForever(observer as Observer<in Any>)
        }
    }

    override fun onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow()
        for((liveData, observer) in autoObservers){
            liveData.removeObserver(observer as Observer<in Any>)
        }
    }

    protected fun<T : Any> LiveData<T>.observe( observer: Observer<T> ){
        autoObservers.add(this to observer)

        //if it's not attached, onAttachedToWindow will do the observation
        if(isAttachedToWindow){
            observeForever(observer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In option 2. Why are you setting state to CREATED in onDetachedFromWindow(). Shouldn't we be setting it to destroyed?

Comment: @Renegade if you remove the view from a parent and add it to another (or some other scenarios), it gets onDetached and onAttached, and setting the lifecycle to DESTROYED will cause to remove observers. Also, you cannot change a lifecycle to anything after you set it to DESTROYED and in those scenarios, the app would crash.